# Associate DocumentDB's document id to class property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to associate a Document's unique ID to a property in my class?

For eg:

```
public class Product
    {


        //Associate this to ID
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string UserId
        {
            get;
            set; 
        }

        public string ProductName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

The thing is, I dont want to create and maintain unique Ids for my objects but reuse the Id that DocumentDB creates after writing a document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you decorate your unique id using JsonProperty attributes then you can use your fields as the unique id, instead of having another id field on every document.

and example is;

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I had actually tried this. The thing is the document gets persisted like this: {
  "ProductId": null,
  "id": "a50ad275-d0eb-412d-9be8-1d5f728c841a"}. But the nice part is that (which I just noticed BTW) when you read the data back, ProductId gets populated with ID.